# Kendo Angular UI Gauges resize themself after update

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

Im using the [RedialGauge](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/gauges/radialgauge/) from Kendo UI together with angular.

Im loading my data for the gauges dynamically from an api with `rxjs` every 3 minutes, here is my code:

```
interval(2e5)
   .pipe(
      startWith(() => forkJoin(
          this.service.getStatistics(),
          this.service.otherCall()
        )
      ),
      switchMap(() => forkJoin(
          this.service.getStatistics(),
          this.service.otherCall()
        )
      ),
      retryWhen((err) => err.pipe(
          take(3)
        )
      )
   ).subscribe(([statistics, others]) => {
      this.statistics = statistics;
      ...
   });
```

After the init load all is fine and the gauges look like they supposed to
[image]

But after the next update the gauges resize them self randomly
[image]

Comment: Please share a minimal Stackblitz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the result I came up with, it is kinda hacky but it's the only solution that really works.

I basicly reload the component when I want to update the gauges.

```js
public refreshComponent(): void {
   const url = this.router.url;
   this.router.navigateByUrl('/app', {skipLocationChange: true}).then(() => {
      this.router.navigate([url]);
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you surround your radial gauge with a div.

in your div you use a ngIf.

set the value true in your ngAfterViewInit()

something like that:

```
        <div *ngIf="isLoaded">
          <kendo-radialgauge class="kendoChart" [pointer]="[{ value: value }]">
            <kendo-radialgauge-scale [startAngle]="startAngle" [endAngle]="endAngle">            
            </kendo-radialgauge-scale>
          </kendo-radialgauge>
        </div>
```

```
  public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
      this.isLoaded = true;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

The CSS could be the issue here. An example is given below

```
 #gauge-container {
            border-style:solid;
            border-color:red; 
            background:  transparent url(@Url.Content("~/images/gauge-container-partial.png"));
            background-vertical-position: -500% ;
            background-size: 100% 100%;
            width: auto;
            height: 100%;
            text-align: center;
            margin: -10% auto auto auto;
        }

        #SMDRReceiverMonitorChart {
            border-style:solid;
            border-color:blue; 
            width: auto;
            height: auto;
            align: center;
            margin: auto auto auto auto;

            border-color: transparent;
        }

        #gauge-container .k-slider {
           margin-top: -11px;
            width: 140px;

        }
```

**Edit**

Note: Its just an example. Please debug and try to change the css accordingly.